# Pair with generic type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a `Pair` which should take a generic type. I mean, I can pass a `String` to `Int`. How can I achieve that?

Example with the current behavior:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Pair<Boolean, Int>>()
```

Expectation:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Pair<T, T>>()
```

Comment: If you want generic properties, then you need a generic class. Otherwise, how would they get resolved?

Comment: Mostly I want to pass String or Int based on the message type. So I wanted to handle both the cases in one `Pair`. @gpunto

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class Abc<T, U> {

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Pair<T, U>>()

}


fun <T, U> Abc1(): MutableLiveData<Pair<T, U>> {
   return MutableLiveData<Pair<T, U>>()
}
val liveData = Abc<String, Int>()
```

Comment: Mostly I want to pass String or Int based on the message type. So I wanted to handle both the cases in one `Pair`. So, in that case, do I need to create a class?

Comment: You have two options to use Generic type either using generic class/interface or generic functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass either String or Int, a [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) may be the right choice, rather than a generic.

In your case something like:

```
sealed class StrInt
data class Numeric(val value:Int):StrInt()
data class Alphanum(val value:String):StrInt()

val a:Pair<StrInt, StrInt> = Numeric(10) to Alphanum("qwerty")
```